Am I wasting time?
I have a Master degree in Physics. I like Physics and I feel good in Academia. I like to work in research and I want to continue doing that. But I have had some problems in the past and it seems that it doesn't matter how much I can evolve and get better, my past is craved in stone.
I explain myself:
I have a bad Academic records. I mean, not bad at all, but I'm not a genius with grades 9 and 10 in every discipline and classes. Actually, I have a lot of 6, 5.5 and other "bad" grades. I even have 3 failures in classes that I had to take again.
But during the Master I got better. All my grades were A (10/10). But during my Master I made a stupid decision: during the covid I had a lot of issues and decided to pause my Master, I went back and finished it in a new project (I started a project A with my supervisor and we moved to project B, completely different project when things got better and we could work again) with the merit of doing it fast, with good results etc the problem is that in my Master's records, now, it points that I took 4 years to finish the Master. Pausing it instead of quitting and starting over was the bad decision. Because when I apply for a PhD I always have to explain everythng again and again.....
Anyway, I moved from my homecountry to a new country in Europe (I came from South America, another "problem") and oe year applying to PhD programs and I have never got any interview until last month when I got two but have not been accepted in any of them. Both in France. In Germany applications things is complicated because they sometimes even request my high school records................ I don't know why for a PhD they want to see my high school records, but anyway...
I'm feeling like giving up. But the other possible path is working with Data Science, which I have worked before, have some experience, and totally hate it........
For my fellows in Academia: should I give up? I mean, this is the end? there is no more possibilities in trying this PhD?
I'm getting 'old' - close to my 30s, not a genius, not the best bachelor records, a complicated story in my Master...
I am even considering starting over and doing a new Master degree.
Am I wasting my time? don't be afraid to answer, be raw.

"it points that I took 4 years to finish the Master. Pausing it instead of quitting and starting over was the bad decision. Because when I apply for a PhD I always have to explain everythng again and again" I think you may have it backwards. In academia, people do not really care that you took 4 years to finish your Master's (especially during covid!). If you are spending a lot of space in your applications explaining something no-one cares about (namely why you took 4 years) at the expense of what people do care about (your research potential), you are probably shooting yourself in the foot.

@AdamPřenosil , maybe it wasn't clear in the post, but I do not spend space explaining this, only when people ask. And the problem is that they always do ask. "Why you took 4 years in the Master? why there is a gap in your curriculum" and there I am telling them the whole story again...

Ok, I see. In any case, I don't see any reason to regret that you took 4 years to finish your Master's as opposed to quitting it starting over again. Surely quitting and starting over a new Master's in the same field is also something that you would have to explain? If anything, I would say that raises more eyebrows and requires more explanation.

It doesn't have any logic. You finished and have Master degree from EU? I don't see what is wrong. Where do you look for PhD degree?

@AdamPřenosil, quitting and starting over would record as 1.5 years; not having quitted marked in my records as a 4 years studying time. I'm not saying there is a logic, but it is a question that people often ask about. "Can you tell me why you took 4 years to finish a Master?" is a question I always hear...

@looktook, I'm Brazilian and my Master is Brazilian. Now I'm legally living in France and trying a PhD in EU. Usually France or Germany. Germany is usually more complicated because they are really interested in my Math grades from when I was 10 years old ahahah

Why do you think "can you tell me why you quit your first Master's and started over" is not a question that you would hear equally often if you had quit and started over?

@AdamPřenosil, I don't think so because it won't be recorded. I mean, my records now shows "start date 2020, end date 2024", but it could just show "start date 2023, end date 2024".
But this is not the core of the question anyway. Its just one minor issue that I'm facing while humilliating myself to try to enter a PhD

Sure, but I think it's worth straightening out because it seems like you are beating yourself up over something which did not in fact damage your chances. When you apply for a PhD, you are universally or nearly universally asked for your CV which should include your full educational history. You are obsessing about the dates on the formal records relating to your latest Master's degree, but in fact you would have to disclose your unfinished study too. Certainly you could lie and pretend it never happened, but if the university found out that you lied, it would be at least a major red flag.

@AdamPřenosil, I appreciate the comment, but I think you are more obsessed than me with this fact. It is just one among a lot of things I wrote in the post, and I just pointed it out because I am always questioned about this. But thanks for your time

We can’t really say what you should do. We know only a one-sided summary, we have no idea about your actual chances or possibilities, your resources or resolve, …. Maybe you are one step away from landing the perfect PhD position. Maybe not.

I think the low grades cause possible interviewers more reason to worry than a long master, though together they do not help. What you need to ask yourself and present to your future place is: what demonstrates your promise? Why should they take you and not someone else? What do you have to offer that others do not? Is there evidence for you to have done something extraordinary, unusual, out-of-the-box? This can compensate for a less-than-optimal traditional vita. Is there anything like that in your history?

@Dimitri I can't say for Europe, but if you quit and restarted a masters and are applying in the US, you are still expected to report that in your application. There will be a gap between your previous degree and next and you will be asked about that gap, too, and "I didn't disclose all my education" would not be a good answer.

Some of the negatives you list are easily explained. Grades from long past are often, as you know, irrelevant, as people grow. More recent grades are more suggestive of success than early ones. You can't prevent people learning of such things, but you can explain them in a sentence or two: I grew up.
Likewise difficulty in academia in the COVID era is easily explained as many people experienced it and many were disrupted by it.
I don't think you are wasting your time, but you may not be using it effectively. There are two things you can do.
The first is to take an inventory of your options, partly, at least, based on your deep desires. I had some difficulty in the middle of grad study, but was so driven to be a mathematician that nothing else would do. I did need to explore non academic math work for a bit, but had support from faculty members that got me back on track.
The second is to cast a broad net for a position in a doctoral program. Europe is a big place with lots of options. France and Germany alone may not be enough. In particular, you speak Portuguese (with a Brazilian flair, of course), and probably understand Spanish. Your English seems pretty good. The broad net should include a variety of institutions. Not all good things happen at only "top" universities in some ranking.
It might also be worth talking to a counsellor so that you avoid depression, and maybe a different kind of counsellor (academic) who can give you an indication of how your skills can be used generally.
